# Estimating variance of success probability in Poisson-binomial distribution

Tags: beta-binomial-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution

I am looking at a very large yet finite sequence of Bernoulli trials, each with its own probability. From the physical nature of the process, I know that the probabilities $p_i$ of each trial should be normally distributed around some small value $\langle p_i \rangle\sim0.1$ and have standard deviation $\sigma_{p_i}\sim0.005$. My ultimate goal is to estimate the mean and variance of $p_i$ based on the measured sequence of Bernoulli trials.

1. I have grouped the sequential trials in blocks of $N = 1000$. The distribution of $X$ - the number of successes $k$ per $N$ trials - should follow the Poisson-binomial distribution, shouldn't it? Is there a way to estimate the variance of $p_i$ in this case?
2. Plotting frequency vs $k$, I observe that the distribution is broader than the binomial with the success probability $\langle k\rangle/N$. It is surprisingly well described by the beta-binomial distribution, which also gives meaningful values for mean and variance of success probability $p_i$. Is there some limiting case when beta-binomial and Poisson-binomial distributions merge, or is it just a lucky coincidence?
   There is no physical sense for the measured probability to follow the beta-binomial protocol. Furthermore, if I group trials in blocks of $N$ not in the order they were obtained but rather randomly, the variance of the distribution of $X$ (as well as the variance of $p_i$) does not change much. Altogether this makes me think that the data, in general case, could not be described by the beta-binomial distribution.

PS: Sorry if I miss trivial things.

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely a situation where you expect the Poisson-binomial to be well approximated by a Poisson.

That's when each of the p's is small.

In that case all the Bernoulli($p_i$) components are well approximated by a Poisson($p_i$) and then the sum of independent components should be well approximated by a Poisson($\sum_i p_i$).

You don't necessarily require a beta-binomial per se; *any* collection of sufficiently small $p$'s will work fairly well.

It will somewhat over-estimate the variance (all those $(1-p_i)$ terms in the contributions to variance are treated as $1$), but when all the $p_i$ values are small this effect may be small enough that it doesn't cause us difficulty.

In your case the $p_i$'s are all close to $0.1$ which is a tad on the larger side but still the  standard deviation of the sum will only be about $5\%$ ($1/\sqrt{1-0.1} - 1\approx 0.05$) too large which may be close enough for some purposes.

Comment: Thanks, I see your point. I have another parameter in the problem that shows me that overdispersion is a function of this parameter in a different way than the mean $p_i$.
In principle, my naive understanding would be the following: since Poisson distribution approximates both binomial and Poisson-binomial -> there should be some regime when beta-binomial and Poisson-binomial would also be close. Does that make sense?

Comment: Well, sure, if the set of $p_i$'s in the Poisson binomial was close to what you would reasonably see from sampling a beta distribution, in the sense than if we treated the $p_i$'s 'like a sample', their empirical cdf was consistent with a sizable sample from a beta, then the two mixtures (finite for the Poisson-binomial and continuous/uncountable for the beta-binomial) should also be quite similar (apart, perhaps, from the extreme tail). Consider what would happen if you literally sampled a beta $n$ times and called those values the $p_i$'s in your Poisson-binomial.